# AngularJS UI-Router Override $state.href How-To

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using AngularJS UI-Router

We're localizing all of our projects, including locale variable in the URL, and for some technical reasons we don't need to include it in state's URL (since UI-Router generates urls relative to the root / and not the base href). Thus we need to modify how $state.href function works & generate URLs. How could we do so without modifying the core library's file??

We're using v0.2.8
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/aa0355567b60b2b07dadc5efa42cc4c212b99f2b/release/angular-ui-router.js#L1931

Comment: could you provide an example scenario?

Comment: Example for what? I just need to override the core function $state.href, that's the issue. How could I do so without modifying the core library file?